# First word of array value to array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [20] => ADEP EGKK

    [21] => ADES EGLL

    [22] => AOARCID ABC

    [23] => AOOPR ABC

    [24] => ARCID ABC123

    [25] => ARCTYP MD11
```

As you can see the first array key is 20, because the first 19 I unset using preg_match:

```
if (isset($_POST['plan']))
  $fplparts = explode("-", $fpl);
      $pattern = "/FAC|TITLE|BEGIN|END|PT|PTID|ATSRT|ICAOCONTENT/i";

  foreach($fplparts as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $value)){
      unset($fplparts[$key]);
    }
  }
  print_r($fplparts);
```

Now how I would like my array to look like is this:

```
Array
(
    [ADEP] => EGKK

    [ADES] => EGLL

    [AOARCID] => ABC

    [AOOPR] => ABC

    [ARCID] => ABC123

    [ARCTYP] => MD11
```

So basically, I would like to move the first word of each value and make it the key.

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($oldArray as $item)
{
   list($key, $value) = explode(' ', $item, 2);
   $newArray[$key] = $value;
}
```

But there are some limitations, for example you have to be sure that first string (which you want as key) will be unique, otherwise you will rewrite your data. 
Third parameter (`2`) in `explode()` is used to make sure that `ADEP EGKK EGKK EGKK` will result in:

```
[ADEP] => EGKK EGKK EGKK
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's very useful! As you say this only works with unique strings, I however may have multiple ADEP values for example, how would I go about this?

So for example to have:

[ADEP] => EGKK
[ADEP] => EGLL
[ADEP] => EDDN

Comment: Well, you can't have multiple array items with same key, so you have to, for example, add some random postfix (`ADEP_2567874`), counter (`ADEP`, `ADEP2`, `ADEP3`...) ar repeat original key (`ADEP`, `ADEPADEP`, `ADEPADEPADEP`).